# How get the address(location) of the VMT table of a EXE generated by delphi

Tags: delphi

i need to enumerate the classes used in a external application written in delphi 
, so i need access to the VMT table to get that information, but i can't find any documentation about how find the location (address) of the VMT (virtual-method table) in a exe (generated by delphi) file.

Comment: Pedantic note: You simply want to enumerate the class names and their method names? Or you want to be able to invoke the methods?

Comment: @joe, Delphi 2007 , but if you have a method to find the location of any other version of delphi is ok too.

Comment: @Warren just enumerate for the moment. ;)

Comment: How do you know there *is* such a thing? Each class has its own VMT. Why should they all be stored contiguously?

Comment: When you say external application, are you trying to read an EXE file or another process' memory to find the classes used in it?  This is not your own program and you can't change the source?  (And if so... why?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not one single VMT in an .exe file. Each class has its own VMT. There is, AFAICT, no reliable way to enumerate the classes in an executable. I assume the executable is only a file. The only way to do that is to analyze how such data is stored in an .exe file.

But even if the .exe is running, and you have access to one of the objects, you can merely find the VMT of the class of that object (at offset 0 of the object). This will also give you access to the base classes of the class, but that is about it.

Answer (score 3):

Please note that there is a difference in runtime type info and only a VMT. If you need type information (like names of methods and types) that is RTTI and not a VMT; a VMT if you can reach it (you can via a type via the RTTI of a class type see below)will contain a list of pointers to methods and no method mnames, parameter information etc etc. Delphi does not create information like IDispatch  for each and every class/interface..

Up to Delphi 2007 you do not have a list of all types, later versions are probably the same but I am not sure. If you have a map file you can get some data from that or you can use some heuristics to search through the file: types in Delphi are always prepended with a pointer to self (eg e PPTypeInfo pointing to the PTypeInfo). Since a PTypeinfo also has a specific format you can detect these quite easily with a scan through the executable.

Once a PTypeInfo is found you can parse the data that follows yielding the typename and following that you have the TypeData. For class types here you can find a poiter to the class which contains the VMT at possitive offsets. Types containing published methods / properties will have those after the type data. You can find all details of the structures in the unit TypInfo.

You will never find all addresses of all methods except in a map file; only methods with RTTI (eg are published) have an address with a name. Only a selected set of types have RTTI (later Delphi's have new RTTI information but I do not know their construct in a module).

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible to some extent!

To depict it, what you need is a kind of **Class browser** for **EXE** file similar to the way the IDE does with pascal unit.

- [Interactive Delphi Reconstructor](http://kpnc.org/idr32/en/) is one the best advanced application of the concept.
- [DeDe 3.50.02 Build 1619](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Programming/Debuggers-Decompilers-Dissasemblers/DeDe.shtml) too (with Source code included?).

The source code of **Revendepro** illustrate the way to tackle it.

Excerpts from *http://www.ggoossen.net/revendepro/findingClasses.html* (seems to be a dead link now):

---

```
  I := Code - vmtSelfPtr;
  while I < Code + CodeSize do
  begin
    // vmtSelfPtr must point to itself.
    if PPChar(I + vmtSelfPtr)^ = I then
    begin
        if PPChar(I + vmtParent)^ = nil then
        try
          // If no classParent then class can be object
          if (not UsePackages) and (TClass(I).ClassName = 'TObject') then
            // if class if object add it to classes.
            Add(TClass(I))
        except
          on EAccessViolation do
        end
        else
          // className must be in the code section.
          // classParent must be in the code section or the import section (when it is imported).
          if (PPChar(I + vmtClassName)^ <= Code + CodeSize) and
             (PPChar(I + vmtClassName)^ >= Code) and
             (((PPChar(I + vmtParent)^ <= Code + CodeSize) and
               (PPChar(I + vmtParent)^ >= Code)) or
              ((PPChar(I + vmtParent)^ <= ImportStart + ImportSize) and
               (PPChar(I + vmtParent)^ >= ImportStart))) then
          // Add possible class to possible class list.
          PossClasses.Add(I);
    end;
    Inc(I, 4);
  end;
   // Can't be more then 1 TObject.
  if (not TPEFileClass(PEFileClass).UsePackages) and (Count > 1) then
    raise EDecompilerError.Create('There can only be one TObject.');
```

---

```
  // If no classParent then class can be object
  if TClass(I).ClassName = 'TObject' then
    Add(TClass(I)) // if class if object add it to classes.
```

---

```
    // Add Classes to the list which parent is in the list.
  repeat
    Added := False;
    for J := PossClasses.Count -1 downto 0 do
    begin
      // Try to find parent class in classList
      if FindClass(TClass(PossClasses[J]).ClassParent) <> nil then
      begin
        // Class in class list
        Add(PossClasses[J]);
        PossClasses.Delete(J);
        Added := True;
      end;
      // Try to find parent class in a other package.
      for K := 0 to High(PEFiles) do
        if PEFiles[K].Classes.FindClass(TClass(PossClasses[J]).ClassParent) <> nil then
        begin
          // Class in class list
          Add(PossClasses[J]);
          PossClasses.Delete(J);
          Added := True;
          Break;
        end;
    end;
  until not Added;
```

Disclaimer: I never tested these codes.